# Moving objects on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Let's say I have 5 objects in an array and I move all them along x-axis like this:

```
vx = 5;

for (i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
 objects[i].x += vx;
}
```

I would like to make this. 
If any object from array 'objects' hit PointA, move all objects from that array to left side, for example set vx *= -1;

I can make only this:

```
for (i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
 // move right
 objects[i].x += vx;

 if (objects[i].hitTest(PointA))
 {
  // move left
  vx *= -1;
 }
}
```

This will change object's direction, but I need to wait all objets hit PointA.

How to change the direction of all objects in array, if any of them hit PointA?

Comment: It looks like you want to change direction once **any** of your objects arrives at your destination, correct?  You're not looking to reset them all to their origins instantly, but rather, continue incrementally moving them in reverse once one reaches PointA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know action script but you should set a boolean outside the for loop, like bGoingRight

Check that this is true and move objects right, if its false move the objects left. When you pass the hitTest you should changed the boolean to false.

Rough Example

```
  var bGoRight:Boolean = true;

  for (i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
  {
    if(bGoRight)
    {
    // move right
    objects[i].x += vx;
    }
    else
    {
     // move left
     vx *= -1;
    }

    if (objects[i].hitTest(PointA))
    {
     // if any object hit the point, set the flag to move left
     bGoRight = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Im not sure if you understand my question.

Comment: I can easy make if object1 hit pointA move object1 to left, then if object2 hit PointA move object2 to left and so on... But how to make if object1 hit PointA, move all other objects to left, not just object1?

Comment: All objects will go left if the bGoRight is set to false because you will check that when you draw them. So when an object hits PointA just switch bGoRight from true to false.

Comment: Please give me an code example, cause it does not make sense to me at all.

Comment: There you go I gave an example

Comment: could you please clarify what your trying to do? So far it sounds like you have five movie clips going in a line towards a point. Then what? I'd be glad to help you out if you can help me make sense of your question.

Comment: I see now what you are talking about JMG, I cannot belive it could be done so easy :) Thank you everyone guys, now I can move objects left and right very easy.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need to check the objects that have already hit PointA, store them, then check if the updated storage count is equivalent to your objects array. Then when that case is satisfied you can change the `vx` variable. This could look something like this:

```
//set a variable for storing collided object references
//note: if you are doing this in the IDE remove the 'private' attribute
private var _contactList:Array = [];

for (i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
     // move right
     objects[i].x += vx;

     if (objects[i].hitTest(PointA))
     {
          if( contactList.length == objects.length ) {
             // move left
             vx *= -1;
             //clear our contact list
             contactList.length = 0;
           } 
           else if ( noContact( objects[i] ) ) {
               contactList.push( objects[i] );
           }
     }
}
```

Then the function in the else if statement `noContact()`, again if you are doing this in the IDE you will need to remove the `private` attribute.

```
private function noContact( obj:* ):Boolean {
    if ( contactList.indexOf( obj ) != -1 ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Another way you can do this is like this (a boolean way as stated in the other answer), but is reliant on your storage setup correct:

```
//set this variable for directionRight (boolean) 
private var directionRight:Boolean = true;

for (i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
{
     // move right
     objects[i].x += vx;

     if (objects[i].hitTest(PointA))
     {
          //we are moving to the right, object[i] is the last object
          if( i == objects.length-1 && directionRight ) {
             // move left
             directionRight = !directionRight;
             vx *= -1;
           } 
           else if ( i == 0 && !directionRight ) ) {
               // move right
               directionRight = !directionRight;
               vx *= -1;
           }
     }
}
```